# Can form submit file(s) to ASP.NET Core controller action without knowing field name in advance?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.x and have a form that is dynamically generated (I don't know how many fields may be on the page or what their names are). This is working fine, except for the "file" input.

One of the possible field types on this form is a "file" input, to allow users to upload files to the site.

In this scenario, I don't necessarily know what the field's name is, so I need to create a controller action that is something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> HandleWorksheet()
{
    ...
    if (field.FieldType == FieldType.FileUpload)
    {
        var uploadedFile = Request.Form.Files.[field.fieldName];
    }
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, the above is not working. In fact, Request.Form.Files is empty.

I have verified that the form is submitting the file, and the following code will work, if I know the field name ahead of time (e.g., "myFieldName") and put it in the action's signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> HandleWorksheet(IFormFile myFieldName)
{
    ...
}
```

Is what I am trying to do possible in ASP.NET Core 2.x?

Why is Request.Form.Files empty?

The form is posting with the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute set.

Comment: I just made a .NET Core 2.1 web app and made a file upload and it seems to work. What does your client side look like? If your file input is missing a `name` attribute then I don't think it will get picked up.

Comment: @KSib Thanks. I am running 2.1 and the `name` attribute is present on the file input. Are you using `Request.Form.Files.[field.fieldName]` to retrieve the file?

Comment: This also works fine for me. I end up with a `Request.Form.Files.Count` of 1 and can access the specific file using `Request.Form.Files["NameIUsed"]`.

Comment: Try this in your example: `var formCollection = await Request.ReadFormAsync(); var uploadedFile = formCollection.Files[field.fieldName];`.

Comment: Thank you, to everyone who commented. For whatever reason, my code is now working. I can't see that I have done anything differently that would fix the issue. I will update my question if I figure out how this get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

change this :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> HandleWorksheet(IFormFile myFieldName)
```

to this :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> HandleWorksheet([FromForm]IFormFile myFieldName)
```

this is worked for me .